# How can I free space on a Ubuntu Usb drive?

Tags: 12.04, live-usb, user-space

I'm very new in the Ubuntu family (I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS , just 2 days ago, I must learn Linux for college).

Second of all, English is not my native language, but I'll try to be as clear as possible).

I installed Ubuntu on a 1 GB flash drive using Universal USB Installer, following the instructions on the Ubuntu.com. It worked just fine.

So i started using the Terminal, to learn about commands, and I edited a text file, a few times, and after a few hours when I tried to save the text file again it displayed me the " low disk space .." message.

I think it also stored the Firefox history/cache.

Anyway, my question is, how can I clear the space?

Side note: while using Universal  Usb, it asked me for the size of persistent folders ( or something like that)  and i specified 200 MB, thinking that this is for file storage. Have I done good? Or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I recommend you use at least **2GB** or even larger USB stick (1 or 2 GB for persistence) in order to avoid such space problems, and install a program like **Bleachbit**  to clean cache, etc. from time to time.
2. As a temporary solution to the problem with your **present USB drive**, you can try and delete the contents of a number of your (hidden) folders (which you can see when you press **Ctrl+H** in **Nautilus**) in your home folder such as: .cache, .thumbnails, .mozilla, etc.

Comment: thank you Sadi, I've also thought of useing a larger USB ..Right now i'm searching my 8GB stick, hope 6GB persistence should be enough. hah   also i will install bleachbit.. thanks for the quick response

Comment: But use Bleachbit with caution and check/uncheck items only after fully understanding what they mean.

Comment: yes, vasa1, i never click buttons without knowing what they do..don't want to scr*w up my computer..thx :)